# Gimp Python: possible to envoke baump-map interactively

Tags: python-2.7, gimp

I want to envoke GIMP bump-map from a python script interactively.
Is that possible?
If so: how?
GIMP Version 2.10.

The parameters list has a parameter for interactive use, but it seems not to be used?

Answer (score 0):

The `run_mode` parameter is a named parameter in the Python API, so you can do

```
pdb.plug_in_bump_map(image, drawable, bumpmap, azimuth, elevation, depth, xofs, yofs, waterlevel, ambient, compensate, invert, type, run_mode=RUN_INTERACTIVE)
```

However, there is no real promise that this works exactly as `Filters > Map > Bump-map` in recent versions, since this has been replaced by a GEGL implementation and the API is a "compatibility procedure".

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.
Complains about:
 `pdb.plug_in_bump_map(image, farbebene, bumpebene, 135, 45, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, True, False, 1,,run_mode=RUN_INTERACTIVE)`
                                                                                            
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Double comma before `run_mode`

Comment: ok, then it works ... but it's not interactively.
Looks as if that additional parameter at the end is just ignored.